# Under $\sum_n x_n = \infty$ and $\sum_n x_n^2 < \infty$, can it happen that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln (1 + x_n) < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $x_n, n \geq 0$ be a sequence such that $\sum_n x_n = \infty$ and $\sum_n x_n^2 < \infty$. Under this assumption Can it happen that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \ln (1 + x_n) < \infty$

Answer (score 2):

No, the condition $\sum x_n^2<\infty$ implies $x_n\to 0.$ Since $\ln(1+h)=h+O(h^2)$ as $h\to 0,$ $\ln (1+x_n) =x_n+O(x_n^2).$ Because $\sum (x_n+O(x_n^2))$ is the sum of a divergent series and a convergent series, it diverges.

Answer (score 2):

It can't, and this is easily seen with equivalents: as $\sum x_n^2$ converges, $x_n\to 0$ when $n\to\infty$, so that
$$\ln(1+x_n)\sim_{n\to\infty} x_n.$$
Now two series with asymptotically equivalent general terms both converge or both diverge.

Answer (score 1):

A counterexample, $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$. $\sum\limits_{n}x_n^2=\sum\limits_{n}\frac{1}{n^2}<\infty$, but using [this inequality](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3615890?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)
$$\frac{1}{n+1}\leq\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}\leq\frac{1}{n}$$
which leads to a [diverging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#targetText=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20harmonic%20series,of%20the%20string's%20fundamental%20wavelength.) series.